# Binary String representation for directed trees or forests

Tags: graph-theory, binary

Consider $G=(V,E)$ to be a directed acyclic graph with indegree at most one. $G$ is also called a forest. Is there a binary string of length $|V|$ that represent $G$? How to construct it?